# Swift: Reusing one ViewController For a CustomTab

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I need help please, i have library call CarbonKit that switch between ViewControllers, it behaves the same way as the tabs on Android, the problem i have now is that the number of tabs, or viewController to be used will be dynamic, it can be two, three or four, the viewControllers has just a tableView inside them, how can i create one viewController and reuse it for all the tabs.
This is where i need to use the Logic.

```
lazy var firstChildTabVC: UIViewController? = {
    let firstChildTabVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecentVC")
    return firstChildTabVC
}()
lazy var secondChildTabVC: UIViewController? = {
    let secondChildTabVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecentVC")
    return secondChildTabVC
}()
lazy var thirdChildTabVC : UIViewController? = {
    let thirdChildTabVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecentVC")
    return thirdChildTabVC
}()

extension TrendVC: CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate{

    func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
    var vc: UIViewController?
    switch index {
    case TabIndex.firstChildTab.rawValue :
        vc = firstChildTabVC
    case TabIndex.secondChildTab.rawValue :
        vc = secondChildTabVC
    case TabIndex.thirdChildTab.rawValue :
        vc = thirdChildTabVC
    default:
        return UIViewController()
    }

    return vc!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many tabs as you want.
**But think about iphone 5 or 6 or 7 users.** How do they tap on your tab if your tab number is more than 5?

I think it's very important than to inform you about the solution of creating multiple tabs.

Comment: Actually, the tabs I am creating is like the one on Android, it's not a bottom Tab.

Comment: there is no feature in iOS. You need to customize  dude. :(

Comment: I have edited my question to show what i am trying to do.